# Construct a simple index matrix from a zero matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

Suppose

```
A = zeros(5,3);
X = [1;2;3;2;1];
```

What I want to obtain is the following: for each of the five rows of A, replace a "0" with a "1", and the position of the replacement is indicated by the vector X. So in this simple example, the matrix to be obtained is

```
 1     0     0    
 0     1     0
 0     0     1
 0     1     0
 1     0     0
```

Is there a good way to get a matrix like this without involving loop over rows?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Jie Wei - I've added the MATLAB tag. If this is incorrect, please edit and replace it with the proper tag.

Comment: This has been asked to death.  See the duplicate.  For the duplicate, simply transpose the final result to achieve what you want.

Comment: @beaker Thanks, Beaker.

Comment: @rayryeng. Thanks, the "sparse" way works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
A(sub2ind([5, 3], (1: 5)', X)) = 1
```

I don't have `MATLAB` with me right now, but it works in `Scilab`.

Comment: Works in MATLAB! In general for `A` n-by-m and `X` n-by-1: `A(sub2ind([n,m], (1:n)', X)) = 1`

Comment: @Geoff  Thanks for the generalization!  In my haste to post, I hard-coded it for a 5 x 3 matrix.